# Help Transposing complicated Equation for coding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\ln(k) = 36.981 + 36.72\left(\frac{\ln(1-\operatorname{RH})}{1.67T - 285.655}\right)^{\frac{1}{2.491-0.012T}} + 0.244\ln\left(10^{-\operatorname{pH}}\right) - \frac{14300}{T+273.15}$$

I am trying to solve the above equation for $T$ if $k$, $\operatorname{RH}$, $\operatorname{pH}$ are all known. I am trying to create a graph of this equation in code, by varying $k$ and $\operatorname{RH}$ to generate multiple lines.

Any assistance would be appreciated! I just keep getting very confused!

Comment: Since $T$ is inside and outside of an exponent, you won't be able to isolate it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, could I isolate for RH then?